# react dando erro

Tags: javascript, react, syntax-error

estou fazendo um formulario em react e esta dando esse erro

'''

```js
    '''
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
UserCrud.updateField

  48 | 
  49 | updateField(event) {
  50 |   const user = { ...this.state.user};
> 51 |   user[user.target.name] = event.target.value;  /* usa nome do input procura propriedade ,diz os atributos ,setou valor do input*/
  52 |   this.setState({ user }) /* passa user direto do ecma 2015 */
  53 | 
  54 | } 
View compiled
onChange

    

  63 |     <input type="text" className="form-control"
  64 |     name="name"
  65 |     value={this.state.user.name}
> 66 |     onChange={e => this.updateField(e)}
     | ^  67 |     placeholder="Digite o nome ..."/>
  68 |     
  69 | </div>
View compiled 
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro deve estar nesta linha

```
user[user.target.name] = event.target.value;  /* usa nome do input procura propriedade ,diz os atributos ,setou valor do input*/
```

A função não está recebendo um parâmetro "user", o nome do parâmetro é "event". o "user" é a variável que guarda o valor do state "user, dentro dele não existe "target".

Altere para:

```
user[event.target.name] = event.target.value;  /* usa nome do input procura propriedade ,diz os atributos ,setou valor do input*/
```

Comment: obrigado irmao tava quebrando a cabeça